# Permissions changed after Mail.app and associated data crash

Tags: macos, email, permissions, crash, apple-mail

I experienced a major Mail.app crash on Snow Leopard couple of days ago.

It took me hours to be able to make the folder structure usable again by Mail.

I changed permissions back to 755 for all subfolders starting from and including ~/Library/Mail

Mail now works again but settings such as folder order in the left side bar and mail ordered by date in some folders don't persist anymore.

Any idea?

Thxs for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting or double checking that you have the proper preferences from `com.apple.mail.plist` in your Preferences folder in your Library folder. (`~/Library/Preferences`) The settings are stored in that file.

Comment: Thxs for the input, I forgot this point.

BTW, I forgot to mention that files have "double" protection settings, i.e. "system" and "everyone" are mentioned twice with the same prot level each time.

Ain't that strange?

Comment: @Olivier Are you the owner of the file?

Comment: yes I'm the owner but, strangely, the root ~/Library/Mail folder didn't have the right protection settings.

After changing this, it came back to original behavior.

I was alerted by the fact I had a similar issue on a USB disk not displaying its icon nor customized folder icons any more.

Setting prots back to original and rebooting did the job.

Thanks for your input anyway